# How to knitr all bash codes with knitr, WSL and Windows RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to knitr bash codes in my Rmarkdown document:

````
```{bash}
echo $PATH
```
````

but the following  error (summarised) occurred:

```
running: bash  -c "echo $PATH"

Quitting from lines 11-12 (test_path.Rmd) 
Error in engine(options) : 
  /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `echo /usr/local/sbin: ... (it showed both the WSL and windows PATH, omitted for brevity)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_group.block -> call_block -> block_exec -> in_dir -> engine
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(cmd, code, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE, env = options$engine.env) :
  running command '"bash"  -c "echo $PATH"' had status 1
Execution halted
```

I tired the same code on a Ubuntu machine and the knitr worked well. I have set RStudio terminal to be Bash(WSL) and Rmarkdown code chunk is able to run the programmes I installed in WSL's bin. There is also no issue when trying to knitr commands like `pwd`

Can I ask if there is any configuration I can set in order to knitr all bash codes, please?